# What domains do I need to whitelist to allow Spotify ads to work?

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi, spotify

I am using [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) to block advertising on my local network.

However, this breaks Spotify (installed via Snap), since the ads are blocked and streaming stops.

**What URLs should I whitelist in order to allow Spotify ads to stream on the network?**

Here is the Spotify Snap info below:

```
snap-id: pOBIoZ2LrCB3rDohMxoYGnbN14EHOgD7
channels:
  stable:    1.1.10.546.ge08ef575-19 2019-07-22 (36) 189MB -
  candidate: 1.1.12.449.g4109e645-38 2019-07-29 (38) 196MB -
  beta:      ↑                                             
  edge:      1.1.12.449.g4109e645-38 2019-07-29 (38) 196MB -
```